# How do "Object()" and "new Object()" differ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, new-operator

In JavaScript, what's the difference between

```
var x = Object();
```

and

```
var x = new Object();
```

?

Comment: @Babiker: Yep, that's the question I was looking for, but it turns out it's not similar at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pulled directly from the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

### 15.2.1 The Object Constructor Called as a Function

When Object is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

### 15.2.1.1 Object ( [ value ] )

When the Object function is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following steps are 
taken:

1. If value is null, undefined or not
   supplied, create and return a new
   Object object exactly as if the
   standard  built-in Object
   constructor had been called with the
   same arguments (15.2.2.1).

   **In Short:** `new Object([ value ])`
2. Return ToObject(value).

### Notes:

**[ ]** Is A common way to mark a parameter as optional.

**ToObject** Is a very simple operation that is defined in section 9.9.

Comment: So it called as a function with no arguments what does it do? Convert `undefined` to an object?

Comment: It simply returns the equivalent of calling `new Object()`.

Comment: @Skilldrick: It would "create and return a new Object object exactly as if the standard built-in Object constructor had been called with the same arguments." So it would be the same as simply saying `new Object()`.

Comment: So there is no difference between `Object()` and `new Object()`?

Comment: @Jens - The final result is the same. The only difference being a layer of redirection to the internal method **Construct**.