# Why the Javascript global objects differ when called with new operator

Tags: javascript, new-operator

On many sites, I have read that for example these two are different:

```
var s1 = String('s1');     // typeof s1 == 'string'
var s2 = new String('s2'); // typeof s2 == 'object'
```

The same applies on booleans, numbers, etc.

However, I did not find any useful information on WHY these two constructs produce different kind of objects. Is there any specific reason for that? Are there any cases when I would leverage both approaches?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080655/how-do-object-and-new-object-differ-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: There are basically no common cases to use the `new` operator with `String()`, `Number()` or `Boolean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mini FAQ for you.

#### Why are there `String` and `Number` objects?

Primitive values, like `"foobar"` or `123` cannot have properties and methods, so there must be objects that actually hold these.

#### How `String` and `Number` objects are used?

They're used implicitly by the engine itself. Every time you assess a property of a primitive, the engine creates a new implicit object just for this (this is called "autoboxing") . For example `x = "foobar".length` is turned into this:

```
 temp = new String("foobar")
 x = temp.length
 delete temp
```

#### Can I use `String` and `Number` objects in my own code?

You can, but hardly need. Due to automatic boxing, you can call all objects' props and methods directly on primitive values. Also, primitives and boxed objects behave differently under some circumstances, e.g. `if(x)...` vs. `if(new String(x))...`.

#### What are `String()` and `Number()` functions?

These are constructors for `String` and `Number` objects. Additionally,  when called directly, without `new`, they perform type conversion, i.e. return a new primitive (not object) of their respective type. In pseudocode, the logic behind `String` is like this:

```
function String(primitiveValue) {
     primitiveString = convert_to_string(primitiveValue)
     if called with new
         return new StringObject(primitiveString)
     else
         return primitiveString
```

Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.1

#### Are direct calls to `String()` and `Number()` useful?

Yes! Every time a type casting is required you want to use these. Some people prefer hacks, like `+x` instead of `Number(x)` or `x+""` instead of `String(x)`, but explicit casting looks cleaner.

#### Why `typeof new String()` is `object` and not `string`?

Everything created by the means of `new` is an object, no matter which specific constructor is used.

Comment: Thanks @thg435 for exhausting FAQ. Just one more question - Is there a reason why new String() returns an object of type 'object'? Instead, I would naturally expect to return new object of type 'string'.

Comment: @PavelLobodinský: no, "string" is a primitive type, all objects are of type "object".

Comment: I see. I am confusing typeof with Java's instanceof. Thanks for explanation, now it makes much more sense - everything whose typeof != 'object' is a primitive type.

Answer (score 3):

```
var s1 = String('s1');
```

Calls the function `String` which returns a string primitive.

```
var s2 = new String('s2');
```

Calls `String` as a constructor which returns an object, that is an instance of `String`.

`String` knows when it's called in a non-constructor context. The creator of the language has deliberately decided not to return an object in that case.

The only useful purpose I can imagine for the first example is type conversion, like `String(4)`, which creates `'4'`. But there are other ways to achieve this.

There does not seem to be a good use case for the second example. Directly creating a wrapper object can even be harmful when the code expects a primitive. E.g.:

```
var s2 = new String('s2');
doSomethingUseful(s2);

function doSomethingUseful(aParameter) {
  if (typeof aParameter === 'string') { //s2 isn't
```

Comment: When would you recommend using `new`?

Comment: @nnnnnn never ;) Directly using wrapper objects doesn't make much sense. Do you think that this should be part of the answer?

Comment: Well, it would be more complete given that you did suggest a purpose for the version without `new`. (Though using `Number()` in a similar way is a more likely scenario than using `String()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Well String(), Function() or Boolean() are all objects of Function reference type.

Before discussing the question u should know there are two data types in javascript.
1)Primitive -for simple string,number,undefined,null,object values etc. cantaining variables.They can be differentiated by typeof operator.For object this will only tell if the given variable contains reference type of data and not what kind of reference type.
2)reference types-they are just like classes in other oop languages.They are the types of objects that can be created by javascript.Some Examples are-function,Date,regex,primitive Wrapper Type etc.They can be differentiated by instanceof operator.

Primitive wrapper Types-The are actually the objects that contain the primitive values but they behave like objects passing their values by reference.They are created by calling the constructor functions with new operator.Ex-                                           String-They are objects containing String kind of Values.Syntax for creating these objects

```
var str=new String("s2")
```

here str behaves as an object.

```
typeof(str)=="object"
```

Whereas just calling String() is just any calling any ordinary function whose only purpose is to convert any other primitive value into string.

```
var s1 = String('s1');     // typeof s1 == 'string'
```

I hope I was clear.If you have any doubts then ask them

Comment: "They are created by calling the constructor functions" - Just calling a function does not create an object ^^

Comment: Yes, "They are created by calling the constructor functions."

Comment: Buddy as in example we need to use new operator to create an instance of object by calling Constructor function.I also wrote this-Whereas just calling String() is just any calling any ordinary function whose only purpose is to convert any other primitive value into string.

Comment: Well, then you should write "They are created by calling the constructor functions **with the new operator**".

Comment: I forgot buddy but I wrote in example. I am writing it now. You win.